# Some variables not listed when creating feature

Tags: 7, features, strongarm

I'm building a feature that includes modules settings stored as variables. Strongarm module is great for that but for some reason, [pathauto_entity](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto_entity)'s module variable called `pathauto_entity_available_entity_types` is not listed as available strongarm variable when I'm creating new feature.

The variable is listed on Strongarm's admin page when I go to `admin/config/development/strongarm`.

Any ideas why this is happening? Is it strongarm or maybe CTools issue?

The variable exists in database and I can read it with drush without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that variable is showing up in the Strongarm admin page, then it means that it's already strongarmed - it probably already exists in another Feature. Use the grep command to search for instances of it in your codebase:

`grep -irn 'pathauto_entity_available_entity_types' [codebase-dir]`

I bet that will turn up an existing Feature that is managing that variable.

You can't export the same variable to more than one Feature. But you can override it with the Features Override module.